# ip camera view for android application in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-camera, android-camera-intent, ip-camera

I would like to make an android application. like this one
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ichano.athome.camera

One android phone camera will be accessible by another mobile through app with push talk feature. 
Is there is a library for ip camera view. I did my search and came to know that, i need public ip to get access of camera and live streaming, but what about push talk feature?
Is there any other workaround or thing which can be done to develop application like this?